# Как по нажатию кнопки показать картинку и текст?

Tags: wpf, winforms

Я хочу, чтобы картинка и текст появлялись после того, как я нажму на кнопку.

Как это сделать?

Comment: Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Answer (score 1):

Можно сделать таким образом:

```
<Button Click="someButton_Click">
    <Button.Content>
        <StackPanel Name="someContent" Visibility="Hidden">
            <TextBlock Text="Button Content"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Button.Content>
</Button>
```

И обработчик события:

```
private void someButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    someContent.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Способ сделать это в рамках MVVM — привязать команду к кнопке, по приходу команды выставить изменить булево свойство с `false` на `true`. К свойству привязать видимость нужного блока UI через `BooleanToVisibilityConverter`.